# How do I add multiple accounts (machine, login, password) to my VIM .netrc file?

Tags: linux, vim, .netrc

I have been just connecting to one server via **.netrc** and it worked fine but now I need to be able to connect the original server and a new account. When I add new account information (`machine`, `login`, `password`) it just signs into the original account that comes first in the .netrc file.

So right now my VIM .netrc file looks like this:

```
machine oldsite.com
login old_username
password oldpassword

machine newsite.com
login new_username
password new_password
```

**How can I make VIM/.netrc ask me which account I want to sign into?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my problem was not in the .netrc file but in my .vimrc file. What I had to do was create a new mapping to ftp to newsite.com. So this is what I have in my .vimrc to get it working

```
map <silent> ;n :e ftp.newsite.com/public_html/<CR>
map <silent> ;o :e ftp.oldsite.com/public_html/<CR>
```

The reason for my trouble was that I forgot all about the shortcut ';o' being assigned just to oldsite.com. To be more clear, I had basically forgotten exactly how it all worked. Only by back tracking through all relevant files did I figure it out.