# Connect to ftp using .netrc with multiple accounts

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I have created a `.netrc` file so i can have some macros and automatically make some standard operations inside my ftp server.

The problem is that now every time i connect to this machine it always connects with the same account automatically ,without giving me the option to select an account for this machine.

I found this question inside stackoverflow,but seems that there is no answer that can help me.

[Link to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575312/how-do-i-add-multiple-accounts-machine-login-password-to-my-vim-netrc-file)

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a .netrc file, each line referring to a particular machine looks like this:

```
machine booster    login baxter  password swordfish
machine wooster    login francis password sw0rdf1sh
```

This will define the logins for two machines: *booster* and *wooster*. If you put in a line like this:

```
default  login root  password secret
```

This will be used for any other machines you haven't already listed.

Macros can be defined for each machine, and are defined after the `machine` or `default` line. The macro is defined by the line `macro` followed by the macro name. If the name is `init`, that macro will be executed automatically by the system.

You need to define separate `machine` lines for each machine you are logging into, and then have a `default` line for all other machines (if so desired).

You can also tell `ftp` not to read in the `.netrc` file by doing one of the following:

```
$ ftp -n
```

You can also use another *net resource* file besides the default `.netrc`:

```
$ ftp -N my.netrc.file
```

Comment: Thank you very much,do you know if its possible to pass argument to the macro ?

Comment: I don't believe Macros can take user input. Macros are mainly for doing repetitive tasks such as logging on or switching to a particular directory or doing specific settings.

Comment: Any way to share the *same* pair of credentials across *multiple* machines (hostnames)? By the the manpage description sounds like it's not possible, but might there be any neat tricks to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution for me ( 2 accounts on same host ) was to add a made-up host name to the /etc/hosts file with the same IP address and then use that new hostname in the .netrc file.